# Custom id column issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in my listing model i setup a method

```
def set_listing_number
  listing_number="TM#{created_at.year}#{id}"
end
```

i have a couple of records that was created before i ran the migration to create the listing_number column. i wanted to update all the records at once but keep receiving this error. 
here's the code that i ran that produce the error in console verifying if the method . it works i cannot save the assignment.

```
  listing_number=listing.set_listing_number
 => "TM2014574"
 2.0.0-p247 :003 > listing_number.save
```

> NoMethodError: undefined method `save' for "TM2014574":String

i tried a couple with no success , that i also found here like this one

```
Listing.all.each{|n| n.update_attributes(:listing_number =>"TM#{n.created_at.year})}
```

the question how do i update the previous record at once. probably it's pretty basic but can't figure it out. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# This method in Listing Model
def set_listing_number
  listing_number="TM#{created_at.year}#{id}"
end 

# In controller
Listing.all.each do |listing|
  listing.set_listing_number
  listing.save
end
```

or you can refactor this as

```
Listing.all.each do |listing|
  listing.update listing_number: "TM#{listing.created_at.year}"
end
```

Comment: by the way thanks , i ran the code in the rails console , the value of the listing_number column still say nil .

Comment: can you post a bunch of code you wrote in console?
a screenshot would be more informative rather

Comment: it works , don't worry , the refactor code works the best , thanks

Comment: i update it fine in the rails console , but when i created a new listing , the column was not updated, i set an after_save callback that will call the function after the creation but still nil.

Comment: then try before_save call back
simply set the field with value, then the ORM will do the rest
before_save :set_listing_number

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `save` on a string. You need `listing.save` in your code.